# Asciimath editor

Tags: editors, mathjax

In HTML, it is easy to use asciimath for combinig text and formulas as you just write: text `asciimath expression` text. Does there exist an editor which allow the same functionality?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to mathjax and HTML. While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.

Comment: Ok, i'll try that